# What are these highlighted bars in Datagrip?

Tags: datagrip

I was editing some MySQL in Datagrip and I noticed that brown highlighted bars appeared.

Could anyone tell me what they mean?

Here they are: In the margin I also notice two tiny brown rectangles (see right side of image below)
[image]

[image]

Datagrip = 2020 version.
Theme = Darcula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like breakpoints. Please check for red dot on left gutter next to the line.

Comment: Thanks, I hit `shift shift` and typed `Show Gutter Icons` and hit enter and the break points appeared.

Comment: Sorry, not clear still. Show Gutter Icons should lead just to a setting.